# Real time communicate between android software and ESP8266 in internet network

Tags: android, server, client, real-time, esp8266

I have an ESP8266 and and one android software which i created.
Whenever one new ESP8266 event is accruing, I want it to inform the change to android software immediately.

In the meantime I have a server which works by Restful Commands. Each n(=10) seconds android software sends a HTTP GET request to server to get new changes if happens that is unacceptable for me, because it isn't real time.

(I also created a tcp web server which manage tcp clients (android software and ESP8266) and inform them their event, but it only works in local network and I couldn't run it in internet network...)

What should I do in you'r opinion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with Realtime, You need to go with Realtime Database. I Strongly recommend the `Firebase`.
If you need some help refer these Github repos done by me.

[writing a NodeJS Web API with Firebase Admin SDK and Arduino Code](https://github.com/Sandun-Isuru-Niraj/webapi_for_arduino.git)

This will help you to understand how we sync the Arduino with the Firebase Database.

Then Refer [this](https://github.com/Sandun-Isuru-Niraj/SwitchMe.git) to understand how to write Android application with Firebase real time database.

Also refer the Firebase [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)